# Fading List Of Strings In and Out

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I am pretty new to android development but am currently working on an app. On my login page I would like to have a series of strings fade in then out one string after the other. I have been trying to use an AlphaAnimation and set its repeat mode to REVERSE but I can't figure out how to get the text to change after an element in the list has already faded in then out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Basically, I think this issue resides in the onAnimationRepeat() function, where I end up changing the text of the TextView. Since the onAnimationRepeat() function would fade the text out I guess I would need to wait for the text to fade out before I change text. Do I need a for loop to iterate over the list of strings and run the animation individually on each string?

See current code below:

```
private fun animateLoginBanner() {
        var index = 0
        val bannerText = resources.getStringArray(R.array.login_banner)

        val anim: Animation = AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f)
        anim.duration = 1000
        anim.startOffset = 1000
        anim.repeatCount = bannerText.size - 1
        anim.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE

        anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                textView.text = bannerText[index]
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {}

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
                index += 1
                textView.text = bannerText[index]
            }
        })

        textView.startAnimation(anim)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but maybe you can you toggle a Boolean in your listener. You also need to double your repeat count.

```
        anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            var isReversing = false

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                textView.text = bannerText[index]
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {}

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
                isReversing = !isReversing
                if (!isReversing) {
                    index += 1
                    textView.text = bannerText[index]
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, worked like a charm. I was using a Boolean before but didn't think to declare it in the listener. Also good catch on doubling the repeat count. Since fading is a two part animation I guess that makes sense.